# Django response error 'unicode' object has no attribute '_meta' json

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-1.11, django-jsonfield

I'm using django 1.11 and i'm getting a tough time in storing a Json response.Here's my views.py code

**views.py**

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from .models import addinfomodels
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.core import serializers
import json
# Create your views here.
def addinfo(request):
    batch_year = [2016, 2017, 2018]
    dept = ['AERO', 'BME', 'CIVIL', 'CSE', 'ECE', 'EEE', 'E&I', 'MECH']
    type = ['onecredit', 'core', 'professional', 'openelective']
    return render(request, "cbcsportal/addinfo.html", {'type': type, 'batch': batch_year, 'dept': dept})

def rollvalue(request):
    return request.POST.get('rollno')
# d ={}
def jsonvalue(request):
    d = {"courses":[{"choices": [request.POST.get('choices00') ,request.POST.get('choices10')], "code": request.POST.get('code0'), "name": request.POST.get('name10')}]}

    ds = serializers.serialize('json', d)
    print ds
    return JsonResponse(ds, content_type="application/json", safe=False)


def posttodb(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = addinfomodels()
        data.batch = request.POST.get('batch')
        data.dept = request.POST.get('dept')
        data.typeid = request.POST.get('typeid')
        data.type = request.POST.get('type')
        data.rollno = [rollvalue(request)]
        data.renderJSON = jsonvalue(request)
        data.starttime = request.POST.get('starttime0')
        data.endtime = request.POST.get('endtime0')
        data.save()
        return redirect('addinfo')
```

please help me i'm getting this error

**'unicode' object has no attribute '_meta'**

this is the traceback

**Traceback**:

Traceback:

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SREC_OBA\cbcsportal\views.py" in posttodb
  34.         data.renderJSON = jsonvalue(request)

File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SREC_OBA\cbcsportal\views.py" in jsonvalue
  21.     ds = serializers.serialize('json', d)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers__init__.py" in serialize
  129.     s.serialize(queryset, **options)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\base.py" in serialize
  84.             concrete_model = obj._meta.concrete_model

Exception Type: AttributeError at /cbcs/posttodb
Exception Value: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: add the full stacktrace

Comment: added the stack traceback @YogeshMhaskule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
d = {....}
ds = serializers.serialize('json', d)
#print ds
return JsonResponse(ds, content_type="application/json", safe=False)
```

You are passing a dict to `serialize()`. Django serializer are for serializing django's orm querysets (this is documented, and you could gave found out by reading the traceback).

The proper way to serialize a python dict to json is quite simply to use `json.dumps(yourdict)`. BUT : in your case this is useless anyway, since [`JsonResponse` expects a python `dict` as first argumen](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)t and will take care of the serialization. Also you don't need to set the content type, it's already the default for JsonResponse. IOW, all you need is:

```
d = {....}
return JsonResponse(d, safe=False)
```

As a side note: here:

```
def posttodb(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = addinfomodels()
        data.batch = request.POST.get('batch')
        data.dept = request.POST.get('dept')
        data.typeid = request.POST.get('typeid')
        data.type = request.POST.get('type')
        data.rollno = [rollvalue(request)]
        data.renderJSON = jsonvalue(request)
        data.starttime = request.POST.get('starttime0')
        data.endtime = request.POST.get('endtime0')
        data.save()
```

You're inserting data in your db that are unvalidated, unsanitized user inputs. DONT DO THAT !!! (unless you're happy to have your server hacked by the first script kiddie of course). Use Django forms (in this case `ModelForm` to take care of validation and sanitization.

Comment: Thank you @bruno but i had already tried that but i was unable to save it to db .when doing so i get <JsonResponse status_code=200, "application/json"> is not JSON serializable error

Comment: @ANISHTIWARI a traceback without the matching code is totally useless, but anwyay: bypassing validation and sanitization is NOT the correct solution. What you should do is to customozie your modelform's validation to correctly fill the form's `cleaned_data`. ALL THIS IS DOCUMENTED, so please read the FineManual and learn to use your tools properly.

Comment: actually this formed will be filled only by admin.There's no case of any hacking in this situation as of the environment this form will be filled.so no worries of hacking

Comment: the real problem is that my json response is not saving .i have updated the code n stack traceback @bruno

Comment: Why would you save a JsonResponse in a database anyway ??? This is beyond my imagination... Just save the json itself. And I already answered about why you had an exception in `jsonvalue()`.

Comment: "actually this formed will be filled only by admin.There's no case of any hacking in this situation" => I'm afraid you are overly confident, specially when your view doesn't check who is posting. But well, that's your problem if you get hacked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180503/discussion-between-anish-tiwari-and-bruno-desthuilliers).